# django authentication package: 'auth' not registered as a namespace

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to build a simple website with user authentication based on [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/build-data-product-django-user-management-du107uyuh), but I'm running into the above error. As per the instructions I set a url as folllows:

```
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

I got this error in response: 'auth' is not a registered namespace So I tried to register a namespace as the tutorial repo shows:

```
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace="auth")),
```

then I get the error :
    Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name

I realised that the tutorial is using django 1.8.3, but I'm on 2.0. The issue is resolved when I switch to the same django version in virtualenv, but I'm now having to a change a number of other things across the project to keep it from breaking. Any way to fix without require django 1.8? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL routing syntax has been changed in Django 2.0, maybe try doing:

```
from django.urls import path
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Answer (score 6):

for Django 2.0 syntax should be like this

```
    from django.urls import path
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    <li><a href="{% url 'auth:login' %}">Login</a></li>#do not use this in any template
    <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>#use this in your template
```

Answer (score 1):

(python 3.7 Django 2.1.1) Little bit investigated `django.urls.conf.include` and voilà `url(r'^accounts/', (import_module('django.contrib.auth.urls'), 'accounts', 'accounts')),`

```
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import re_path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^', include('tracks.urls', 'tracks')),
    url(r'^accounts/', (import_module('django.contrib.auth.urls'), 'accounts', 'accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is django 2+, you need to put `app_name = 'x'` in your application's url.py file. For example, if in /project/project/urls.py you have:

```
path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app'))
```

Then in the corresponding url file (in /project/app/urls.py) you need to specify the app_name parameter with:

```
app_name = 'app'  #the weird code
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'), #this can be anything
]
```

Answer (score 0):

django 2+, you need to put **app_name = 'auth'** django.contrib.auth.urls file.
(\python361\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\urls.py)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party I know, but for future reference. If you want to namespace the auth urls, you need to pass the app_name into urls include as well as specifying the namespace, so:

```
path('accounts/', include(('django.contrib.auth.urls','auth'), namespace="auth")),
```

Allows the urls to be referenced as

```
<a href="{% url 'auth:login' %}">Login</a>
```

Note though that the _done urls will no longer work as the PasswordChangeView uses a success_url of password_change_done which it wont find as it's now auth:password_change_done. So if you need to use the password forms, it's probably easier to just use the default non-namespaced urls or override those urls with:

```
path('auth/password_change/', auth.views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('auth:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),
path('auth/password_reset/', auth.views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('auth:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
path('auth/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('auth:password_reset_complete')), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('auth/', include(('django.contrib.auth.urls',"auth"), namespace="auth")),
```